# Creating a pass that would insert a print statement of each basic block in LLVM

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Hi I am trying to create a LLVM pass that would insert a print statement of its basic block names when it traverses them.
I have been facing this run time error and I do not know how to address it.

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"    
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"    
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"    
    
// adding to include IRBuilder    
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"    
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"    
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"    
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"    
    
// adding to include getFunction function    
#include "llvm/IR/Value.h"    
#include "llvm/IR/Instruction.h"    
    
using namespace llvm;    
using namespace std;    
    
extern "C" void printBBname(const char *name) {    
        printf("Basic Block: %s\n", name);    
}    
    
namespace {    
    struct Hello : public FunctionPass {    
        static char ID;    
        Hello() : FunctionPass(ID) {}    
    
        bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {    
            errs() << "Hello: ";    
            errs().write_escaped(F.getName()) << '\n';    
            unsigned count = 0;    
            LLVMContext& context = F.getContext();    
            // below is testing the other ways to iterate through    
            for(Function::iterator bb = F.begin(), e = F.end(); bb != e; ++bb){    
                bb->setName(F.getName() + "_" + to_string(count++));    
                errs() << "Basic Block name: " << bb->getName() << ", size: " << bb->size() << "\n";
                IRBuilder<> Builder(context);
                Module *m = bb->getModule();
                Type *returnType = Type::getVoidTy(m->getContext());
                PointerType *argType = PointerType::get(Type::getInt8Ty(m->getContext()), 0);
                FunctionType *FuncType = FunctionType::get(returnType, argType, false);
                assert(m != nullptr && returnType != nullptr && argType != nullptr && FuncType != nullptr);

                Function *printFunc = Function::Create(FuncType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "printBBname", m);
                assert(printFunc != nullptr);
                Value *str = ConstantDataArray::getString(context, bb->getName());
                Builder.SetInsertPoint(&*bb, bb->getFirstInsertionPt());
                Builder.CreateCall(printFunc, str);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }; // end of struct Hello
} // end anonymous namespace

char Hello::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<Hello> X("hello", "Hello World Pass",
                             false /* Only looks at CFG */,
                             false /* Analysis Pass */);
```

Just in case here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(SkeletonPass MODULE    
    skeleton.cpp    
    
    # Possibly other .cpp files if you have any    
)    
    
target_compile_features(SkeletonPass PRIVATE cxx_range_for cxx_auto_type)    
set_target_properties(SkeletonPass PROPERTIES    
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-fno-rtti"    
)
```

and when I try to change hello.bc, whose source code is hello.c, which goes

```
#include <stdio.h>    
    
void f() {    
    printf("this is function f\n");    
}    
    
void g() {    
    printf("this is function g\n");    
}    
    
int main(int argc, char **argv) {    
    printf("Hello, World!\n");    
    if(argc == 1) {    
        f();    
    } else if(argc == 2) {    
        g();    
    }    
    return 0;    
}
```

and I run it with the command `opt -load ../skeleton/build/libSkeletonPass.so --hello <hello.bc> out.bc`

I face the following error:

```
Hello: f
Basic Block name: f_0, size: 2
Call parameter type does not match function signature!
[4 x i8] c"f_0\00"
 i8*  call void @printBBname([4 x i8] c"f_0\00")
in function f
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: opt -load ../skeleton/build/libSkeletonPass.so --hello 
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '<stdin>'.
2.  Running pass 'Module Verifier' on function '@f'
 #0 0x000056066c0d6fce llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x17cbfce)
 #1 0x000056066c0d4e64 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x17c9e64)
 #2 0x000056066c0d4fa8 SignalHandler(int) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x17c9fa8)
 #3 0x00007f29ffb70420 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x14420)
 #4 0x00007f29ff60d00b raise /build/glibc-SzIz7B/glibc-2.31/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51:1
 #5 0x00007f29ff5ec859 abort /build/glibc-SzIz7B/glibc-2.31/stdlib/abort.c:81:7
 #6 0x000056066c047a0a llvm::report_fatal_error(llvm::Twine const&, bool) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x173ca0a)
 #7 0x000056066c047b2e (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x173cb2e)
 #8 0x000056066b96dfb6 (anonymous namespace)::VerifierLegacyPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x1062fb6)
 #9 0x000056066b8e5da0 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0xfdada0)
#10 0x000056066b8e73a9 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0xfdc3a9)
#11 0x000056066b8e4fb0 llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0xfd9fb0)
#12 0x000056066acd6de0 main (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x3cbde0)
#13 0x00007f29ff5ee083 __libc_start_main /build/glibc-SzIz7B/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:342:3
#14 0x000056066ad3c15e _start (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x43115e)
fish: “opt -load ../skeleton/build/lib…” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

any piece of advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and fish as shell. clang version is 11.0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the error:

```
Call parameter type does not match function signature!
[4 x i8] c"f_0\00"
 i8*  call void @printBBname([4 x i8] c"f_0\00")
```

This means that the signature of your function is:
`void @printBBname(i8*)` but you provided `[4 x i8]`

In different words, `@printBBname` requires `i8*`, but `str` is an array: `[4 x i8]`

To solve this, we have to cast `[N x i8]` to `i8*`

```
llvm::Value *strPtr = Builder.CreatePointerCast(str, argType);
Builder.CreateCall(printFunc, strPtr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I did this, I got ```Invalid bitcast
i8* bitcast ([4 x i8] c"f_0\00" to i8*)
in function f
``` :(